# How to create a listening server in windows server 2008 to recieve files from linux via nc command?

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, push

Right now i have a **linux server** listening at a port to write whatever comes at that port in a file the following way:

```
 nc -l -p 7777 0.0.0.0 | tee some.file
```

And i have a **linux client** that pushes a file to the server the following way:

```
cat ZKDB.db | nc 192.168.0.33 7777
```

Everything works perfectly. But the thing is that i need to **replace the linux server with a windows server 2008 equivalent**

What command or program can i use in windows server 2008 to achieve the same i did in the linux server?

---

Note: the linux client is very old embed system so i don't have much functionalities to hold on to. I barely have telnet, nc, cat, tee, etc.

Comment: Get a netcat build for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Windows ports for Netcat do exist and various versions can be found.
Below are some that I found.

- [Powercat](https://github.com/besimorhino/powercat)
  This a PowerShell port of netcat, so is maybe the most recent and most likely
  version to work.
  You may find a writeup of it [here](https://www.andreafortuna.org/powershell/powercat-a-porting-of-netcat-written-in-powershell/).
- [Netcat on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nc110/)
  The latest version dates from 2018. Sounds good.
- [Netcat by diegocr](https://github.com/diegocr/netcat)
  Dating from 2014. May still be useful.
- [Netcat by joncraton](https://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows/)
  Netcat version 1.11 dating from 2004. May be too old.